# Always getting the correct axis to move on regardless of direction. 2D

Tags: c#, math, xna

I'm struggling to think of the best way of asking this question so forgive me if I don't make much sense but if I move on an an axis, what's the best way of replicating that movement on the opposite axis?

My approach so far has been:

Get the distance from point A to B. 
Flip the axis(So X = Y and Y = X).
Move from point A with this new direction.

Look at the graph below,

The problem I'm getting is this, horizontally/vertically it works fine, so for example if the direction was right, when flipped the direction given would be downwards you'd move down (if using Cartesian coordinate system) if you flip the axis round.

However do it on a diagonal and I run into problems, if I move positive x and positive y and then flip the axis, I still move on the positive for both. What I really want is either a negative x, positive y or a positive X, negative y.

Please can someone explain the mathematical explanation, I feel like I know this but my head seems to be muddled with different tried and tested solutions.

Edit:

[image: Cartesian Plane]

Comment: Can you provide some images to better visual your issue? Also, you might get better support on [GameDev.StackExchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Edited the question, I've tried to add an image but I've done the image incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks Austin for the image fix.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're essentially trying to reflect points across the line y=x (using microsoft style screen coordinates where (0,0) is the top left corner). If so, (20,20) should not change because it lies on that line. What would you want it to become?

Edit:
I just double checked my work. Given a non-directed line from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2), the perpendicular line of equal length with the same midpoint goes from
`((y2-y1+x1+x2)/2,(x1-x2+y1+y2)/2)` to `((y1-y2+x1+x2)/2,(x2-x1+y1+y2)/2)`

Comment: I think I edited the question, but basically if it was 20,20 I'd like the right angle equivalent direction on either side, so either -20,20 or 20,-20

Comment: ok, so you're trying to rotate by 90 degrees.

(x,y) => (-y,x)

Comment: Effectively yeah, basically to expand further I need to get the middle of a line I've already got and then make a line that intersects it.

Comment: So given a line with endpoints (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), you'd like to create another line to intersect it that is the same length but rotated 90 degrees. The intersection should occur at the midpoint of both lines. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly that. I've been doing that before by finding the center of the first line and then trying to flip the distance between the first and second points but as I say it's not working.

Comment: In that case (assuming endpoint order doesn't matter), I believe what you want is the line with endpoints

`((y2-y1+x1+x2)/2,(x1-x2+y1+y2)/2) and ((y1-y2+x1+x2)/2,(x2-x1+y1+y2)/2)`

I haven't double checked my work, but that should be right